# Difference between storing an imageview in a variable and intializing it later, compared to doing it all on the same line(android studio kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android studio development, I am trying to figure out what makes these two codes below different. The code line that needs help is indicated with <----

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 lateinit var diceImage: ImageView  <----

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
    rollButton.setOnClickListener {
        rollDice()
    }

    diceImage = findViewById(R.id.dice_image) <----
}
```

Compared to just declaring and initializing the variable

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
    rollButton.setOnClickListener {
        rollDice()
    }

    val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice_image)<----
}
```

I was following a tutorial and I was wondering what the difference was, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between these two

`diceImage = findViewById(R.id.dice_image)<ImageView>{}`

`val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice_image)`

is just the declaration.  The second line decalared:

`val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice_image)`

because by defining `diceImage` as a variable with the shortcut `:` and adding **Imageview** component then you don't have add the **ImageView** at the end of the declaration like the first line. It's just a short way of declaring **findViewByID** on **android**.